# Web iOS Scroll Bug on Fast Scroll

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css, iphone-web-app

I'm getting a weird UI bug on web on iOS across all three browsers I've tested (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). I'm on an iPhone 14. I have a number of cards that scroll vertically, and I have `overflow-x-hidden overscroll-y-none` on the body. I'm using Tailwind and NextJS.

When I quickly scroll up and down, I eventually get to this situation:

[image]

In the inspector on Safari, I've highlighted the card as the blue box. The blue box is where the card is supposed to be, according to the information in the DOM (and where I want it). Instead the card is showing up tiny and to the left, as you can see. Nothing in the DOM has changed, AFAICT. With a refresh, everything looks normal again.

You can see this behavior for yourself at gregliest.com. On an iPhone, scroll up and down quickly until you see this situation.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is this still an issue ? I tried on my 14 Pro, the bug didn't show

Comment: Yes, I just checked on iOS 16.0.1 and 16.2. You have to scroll up and down fast enough for the cards to stop loading in time, and then eventually they will appear as shown above.

Comment: Did you try the  outline:none on the tag ?

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work.

Comment: One last idea with CSS : `* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important }`

Comment: Yeah nothing, thanks for trying though.